# Bound solutions in scipy ode solver

Tags: python, scipy, range, ode, odeint

I want to solve a high amount of bilinear ODE systems in python. The derivative is this:

```
def x_(x, t, growth, connections):
    return x * growth + np.dot(connections, x) * x
```

I am not interested in very accurate results but in the qualitative behavior, i.e. whether a component goes to zero or not.

Because I have to solve such a big quantity of high-deminsional systems, I want to use a step size as big as possible.

Due to big step sizes it can happen that the ODE goes in one component below zero. This should not be possible since (because of the structure of the particular ODE) each component is bounded by zero. Hence - to prevent wrong results - I would like to set each component manually to zero once it is below.

Furtherly, in the systems that I want to solve it can happen that solutions blow up. I want to prevent this by setting an upper bound as well, i.e. if a value exceeds the bound it is set back to the value of the bound.

I hope I can make my goal understandable giving you the following pseudo-code of what I want to do:

```
for t in range(0, tEnd, dt):
    $ compute x(t) using x(t-dt) $
    x(t) = np.minimum(np.maximum(x(t), 0), upperBound)
```

I implemented this using a Runge-Kutta algorithm. Everything works fine. Just the performance is bad. Therefore, I would prefer using a pre-implemented method like scipy.integrate.odeint.

Thereby, I have no idea on how to set such bounds. An option that I tried was to manipulate the ODE that way, that the derivative becomes 0 once x is above the bound, and (positive) one once x is below 0. In addition, to prevent too high jumps within one timestep, I also bounded the derivative:

```
def x_(x, t, growth, connections, bound):
    return (x > 0) * np.minimum((x < bound) * \
           ( x * growth + np.dot(connections, x) * x ), bound) + (x < 0)
```

Though this solution (especially for the zero-bound) is very ugly it would be sufficient if it worked. Unfortunately, it does not work. Using odeint

```
x = scipy.integrate.odeint(x_, x0, timesteps, param)
```

I get very often one of these two errors:

```
Repeated convergence failures (perhaps bad Jacobian or tolerances).

Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type).
```

They may be due to the discontinuities of my manipulated ODE. There are plenty of threads about these error messages on the internet but they did not help me. E.g. increasing the amount of allowed steps did neither prevent this issue nor is it a good solution for me since I need to use big step sizes. Furtherly, passing the Jacobian did not help either.

Having a look onto the solutions one can see that two types of strange behavior happen when the errors occure:

1. The solution blows in one single time-step up to +-1e250 (that should be impossible since dx/dt is bounded).
2. It first reaches the bound but goes down again (that should be impossible because x is at the bound and therefore x_ is 0).

I would appreciate all hints on how to solve the issue - no matter whether it is help on

- how to prevent the errors in odeint
- how to manipulate the ODE properly or on
- how to write a very fast ODE solver where I can directly implement my needs.

I thank you in advance!

### Edit

I was asked for a minimal example:

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd
rd.seed()
import scipy.integrate

def simulate(simParam, dim = 20, connectivity = .8, conRange = 1, threshold = 1E-3, 
             constGrowing=None):
    """
    Creates the random system matrix and starts a simulation
    """

    x0 = np.zeros(dim, dtype='float') + 1
    connections = np.zeros(shape=(dim, dim), dtype='float')

    growth = np.zeros(dim, dtype='float') + 
                    (constGrowing if not constGrowing == None else 0)


    for i in range(dim):        
        for j in range(dim):
            if i != j: 
                connections[i][j] = rd.uniform(-conRange, conRange)

    tend, step = simParam
    return RK4NumPy(x_, (growth, connections), x0, 0, tend, step)


def x_(x, t, growth, connections, bound):
    """
    Derivative of the ODE
    """
    return (x > 0) * np.minimum((x < bound) * 
                (x * growth + np.dot(connections, x) * x), bound) + (x < 0)


def RK4NumPy(x_, param, x0, t0, tend, step, maxV = 1.0E2, silent=True):
    """
    solving method
    """
    param = param + (maxV,)
    timesteps = np.arange(t0 + step, tend, step)

    return scipy.integrate.odeint(x_, x0, timesteps, param)


simulate((300, 0.5))
```

To see the solution one would have to plot x. With the given parameters I get very often the above mentioned error

```
Excess work done on this call (perhaps wrong Dfun type).
Run with full_output = 1 to get quantitative information.
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) 1) Post a minimal working code showing the problem you are experiencing; 2) have you tried tackling the problem analytically? 3) is `connections` a `n`x`n` matrix or just a vector of size `n`?

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome, @GiulioGhirardo! =) 

1) I am sorry: Which part of working code are you asking for? The Solving algorithm? 

2) I have thought about solving the problem analytically but did not see a way on how to do it. The question is in how many dimension the solution approaches 0. I would have to determine the stationary states and their stability regions. At the moment I do not think there is a way of solving the problem analytically. If you have one, I would be very interested!

3) `connections` is a (partially random) `n x n` matrix.

Comment: I am asking for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) type of minimal working code, try packing down the code

Comment: It looks to me that your problem might be ill-posed: When considering only diagonal matrices for `connections`, you'll get a set of independent ODEs with analytic solutions. Depending on value and on `growth` the solution may be unstable. For divergent solutions, numeric methods, especially in high dimensions, do not work well, as you noted. For a more general case, you might want look at diagonalizable matrices (ones which have a eigen decomposition), where analogous observations hold.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts @Dietrich! The matrices are in general not diogonalizable. It is the other way around: Only the diagonal entries are zeros! Furtherly, the ODE consists not only of the matrix term but also of an exponential growth term. There may be divergence. But as I already mentioned I am not interested in the "real" solution but in the bounded one exactly as I described it above. Think of the problem as of an IVP with a sectionwisew defined (non-continuous) ODE. With this bound the numerical algorithms should work.

Comment: I solved the issue somehow by writing my own extension using cython. Nevertheless, it would be great if anybody knew how to use the (surely more efficiant) builtin algorithms for the solution. I therefore do not regard the question as anwered, though it does not have first priority for me anymore.